# EXT JS - keep grid filtering

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, extjs, extjs4.1

How can I store the filters applied on a EXTJS grid?

Lets say I have a page A with the grid. I filter the grid, go to page B and then the next time I'm on page A, I want the same filters applied?

Its on an MVC application.

Comment: Are you applying the filters with [FiltersFeature](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature) or just applying them programmatically on the store?

Answer (score 0):

`grid.getStore().filters` would give your mixed collection of filters applied to your grid. Save first one or all of them somewhere and then re-apply them using

```
store.filter(...)
```